# Rustacious way of checking if string ends with any suffix from a selection

Tags: beginner, strings, unit-testing, rust

What's the best way to check if a String ends with any of multiple suffixes in Rust?

I have a working, naive solution:

```rust
fn string_ends_with_any(s: String, suffixes: Vec<&str>) -> bool {
    for suffix in &suffixes {
        if s.ends_with(suffix) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    false
}
```

*Note: suffixes could have varying lengths*

As I am quite new to Rust, I would very much appreciate any/all suggestions about how my code can better leverage Rust idioms.

Here are some test cases I need to function pass

```
#[test]
fn empty_suffixes() {
    let s = String::from("5m");
    let suffixes = vec![];

    assert!(!string_ends_with_any(s, suffixes))
}

#[test]
fn empty_string_has_no_suffix() {
    let s = String::from("");
    let suffixes = vec!["txt"];

    assert!(!string_ends_with_any(s, suffixes))
}

#[test]
fn string_ends_with_first_suffix() {
    let s = String::from("foo.txt");
    let suffixes = vec!["txt", "csv"];

    assert!(string_ends_with_any(s, suffixes))
}

#[test]
fn string_ends_with_last_suffix() {
    let s = String::from("foo.csv");
    let suffixes = vec!["txt", "csv"];

    assert!(string_ends_with_any(s, suffixes))
}

#[test]
fn string_doesnt_end_with_any_suffix() {
    let s = String::from("foo.csv");
    let suffixes = vec!["txt", "tsv"];

    assert!(!string_ends_with_any(s, suffixes))
}

#[test]
fn string_ends_in_suffix_but_case_is_wrong() {
    let s = String::from("foo.csv");
    let suffixes = vec!["txt", "Csv"];

    assert!(!string_ends_with_any(s, suffixes))
}
```

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.ends_with

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that's not particularly helpful. I know that `String::ends_with` exists (I use it in my implementation). The question I quite clearly asked was whether there is a  way to test whether a String ends in any number of given strings more effectively than I am.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Iterator:any](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/fn/closures/closure_examples/iter_any.html) to write this in a succinct way:

```
fn string_ends_with_any(s: String, suffixes: Vec<&str>) -> bool {
    return suffixes.iter().any(|&suffix| s.ends_with(suffix));
}
```

Because this pattern returns true on first match of the predicate:

> ```
> for suffix in &suffixes {
>     if s.ends_with(suffix) {
>         return true;
>     }
> }
> false
> ```

Whether this is *rustacious* remains to be seen. I'm by no means an expert in Rust.